# Geo mapping in R

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet

I have a transaction data at country level.

Data Sample:

```
TransID CountryOrigin(CO)  CountryDestination(CD)  COLat         COLong       CDLat        CDLong

1          India               Australia        20.593684     78.962880   -25.274398   133.775136
```

Now i want to link the Country origin and destination with the number of transactions.If the transaction is high then the width of the line will be bigger than the low transaction zone.

I want the visualization more similar to below image
(With the country name label in worldmap)
[image]

Comment: If you find any other way than my answer below suggests to create this plot, I would be happy to have a look into your code. I would also appreciate an upvote or even "the accepted answer" tick if you liked my answer. Also if you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: SUre Martin...i'm working on it and thx for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure, but as far as I understand you are looking for something like this:
http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/

If you want the width of the line bigger in higher transaction zones, you have to set the `lwd parameter` higher in these lines:

```
#Load packages
install.packages("maps")
install.packages("geosphere")
library(maps)
library(geosphere)

#Create a Map
xlim <- c(55.593, 140.9628)
ylim <- c(-30.2743, 40.775)
map("world", col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.05, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

#create a line
lat_india <- 20.5936
lon_india <- 78.96288
lat_aussie <- -25.2743
lon_aussie <- 133.77
inter <- gcIntermediate(c(lon_india, lat_india), c(lon_aussie, lat_aussie), n=50, addStartEnd=TRUE)

#plot the line (lwd represents the width of the line)
lines(inter, lwd=3)
```